# Memcache session handler - what is the item that session_start() adds to the cache?

Tags: php, memcached

`session_start();`  => stores some item into the cache - **what is this item** ?

`session_write_close()`; => stores item with name as session id and value as content from $_SESSION into the cache

Comment: it'll be `session id : array()`. even if you NEVER put anythign into $_SESSION, it'll produce an empty array for you.

Comment: Before you post, please search SO for your question. This has probably been answered already.

Comment: **james.garriss:** Of course, I have searched the answer, but i didn't find any. Is there some existing answer ? Thanks for link.

Comment: **Marc B:** Could you please explain more clearly, what do you mean ? Memcache item with name as session id is already generated by session_write_close() function. But there are +2 existing items in cache after each php session procedure (if the session id is new). If I could dump the content of cache I would see what the item is. Unfortunately it seems that dumping content of memcache is quite problematic

Answer (score 1):

With [memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache)'s session handler, `session_start` will not directly store anything into the cache pool. It'll simply connect to the servers, and attempt to read previous session data into PHP's sesssion thread. Session data will be stored as [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string, and saved under the PHPSESSID generated key when the thread completes, or `session_write_close` is invoked.

You can verify this by running `memcached -vvv`, and interacting with the cache in PHP & telnet.

In PHP's interactive mode, run the following.

```php
php > session_start(); // Connect and read 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
php > print session_id().PHP_EOL;
1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
php > $_SESSION['a'] = 400;
php > session_write_close(); // Write to 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
```

In memcached's verbose output, you should see information about the connection thread (internal state transitions omitted.)

```
// session_start
<28 new auto-negotiating client connection
28: Client using the ascii protocol
<28 get 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
> NOT FOUND 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
>28 END
// session_write_close
<28 set 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2 0 1440 8
> NOT FOUND 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
>28 STORED
<28 connection closed.
```

And then you can verify with telnet

```
telnet localhost 11211
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2
VALUE 1r5v47v4eh5uaem4dnt8a74jk2 0 8
a|i:400;
END
```

quit

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll study it later and I'll give you a feedback. At present my head is full of another unclear things regarding PHP which have greater priority to figure out:)